# Create a flag for a Qt project or use QLoggingCategory

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

This is my first question on this website, I hope I'll do it just fine.

I'm doing a Qt Project at work using a lot of signals and slots and I would like to **create a flag/macro/variable to activate/deactivate the use of std::cout to trace which signal is emitted and which slot is activated**.

This is for debugging purpose, to know how the different components of the application exchange and avoid loops in signals/slots.

More specifically, I would have a flag/variable in my .pro :

```
QT_SIGNALS_SLOTS_LOG = true
```

and in my source code :

```
if(QT_SIGNALS_SLOTS_LOG)
     std::cout << "MyClass::slotMySlot activated" << std::endl;
```

Questions :

**1.** Can I do something like that (using a variable of the .pro in the
    code) ?

**2.** Is there a better way of doing that ?

---

**UPDATE 1**

Burich, this works just fine, thanks

Now I will try to code a Qt macro which I put in my slots and wich does all the work

Example :

```
Q_SIGNALS_SLOTS_LOG();
```

which gets the names of the Class and the Slot and do the

```
ifdef QT_SIGNALS_SLOTS_LOG
     std::cout << "MyClass::slotMySlot activated" << std::endl;
endif
```

Is there a way of doing that ?

---

**UPDATE 2**

I used [QLoggingCategory Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html#details) with this [tutorial](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/03/11/qt-weekly-1-categorized-logging/)

I have a Class in my Utils folder with this code

```
#ifndef SIGNALSLOTDEBUG_H
#define SIGNALSLOTDEBUG_H
#include<QLoggingCategory>


Q_DECLARE_LOGGING_CATEGORY(logSignal)
Q_DECLARE_LOGGING_CATEGORY(logSlot)

inline static void debugSlotF( char const * caller_name )
{
    qCDebug(logSlot) << __TIME__ << caller_name << "activated";
}

inline static void debugSlot(){

}

#define debugSlot() debugSlotF(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)

#endif // SIGNALSLOTDEBUG_H
```

In my code I just call

```
void HorizontalPatternListScene::slotSelectionChanged(int i)
{
    debugSlot();
    ....
```

I get this output :

```
log.slot: 12:06:54 void HorizontalPatternListScene::slotSelectionChanged(int) activated
```

And I can disable the stream by doing

```
QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules(
            "log.slot=true\n"
            "log.signal=false");
```

in my main.cpp

Comment: The "better" way would be using the Qt Logging Framework. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html#details

Comment: Do you want to output these logs all the time when debugging, and not when not debugging? In that case, use the qDebug class: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html

Comment: I don't want ALWAYS want them when debugging
I want to be able to disable them if I want because I imagine that it will at long spam the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set variable in pro:

```
DEFINES += QT_SIGNALS_SLOTS_LOG
```

Test it in code:

```
#ifdef QT_SIGNALS_SLOTS_LOG
     std::cout << "MyClass::slotMySlot activated" << std::endl;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use C++11 features for this, you can so the following:

```
#ifdef DEBUGMYCODE
template<typename... ArgTypes>
inline void print(ArgTypes... args)
{
  // trick to expand variadic argument pack without recursion
  using expand_variadic_pack  = int[];
  // first zero is to prevent empty braced-init-list
  // void() is to prevent overloaded operator, messing things up
  // trick is to use the side effect of list-initializer to call a function on every argument, in order.
  // (void) is to suppress "statement has no effect" warnings
#ifdef _WIN32
  std::stringstream stream;
  (void)expand_variadic_pack{0, ((stream << args), void(), 0)... };

  std::wstring stuff = convert_to_utf16(stream.str());
  WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), stuff.c_str(), stuff.size(), nullptr, nullptr);
#else
  (void)expand_variadic_pack{0, ((std::cout << args), void(), 0)... };
#endif
}
#else
#define debug_print(...)
#endif
```

I use this in [my code](https://github.com/rubenvb/architekton/blob/master/architekton/print.h%2B%2B#L49) as a general "print" function and add [a debug enum](https://github.com/rubenvb/architekton/blob/master/architekton/debug.h%2B%2B#L47) on top to handle debug types being output at runtime.

It handles UTF-8 strings on Windows as a bonus, and handles anything that can be dumped to `std::cout`. You can also change what stream it outputs to, or really whatever the body of the function does.

If the macro `DEBUGMYCODE` is not defined, all calls to `debug_print` are fully removed by the preprocessor.

PS: if it's Qt you're coding, you should really use `qDebug()` which handles this for you in an entirely different manner.

Comment: MMMh, yeah that could do it too !
So I create a class defining that in, for example, a Util folder and I can use it everywhere in my code ?